# WebGL: Beveled smooth anti-aliased circles using GL_POINT?

Tags: webgl, fragment-shader

Sorry for such a long title.

[This is a followup on my old question, which led me to drawing a beveled circle looking like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40947092):

[image: Old dodgy circle]

If you look closely at this image, you can see the pixelation around the edge.

I wanted to smooth this circle with anti-aliasing, and I ended up with this:

[image: New dodgy circle]

If you look closely at this image, you can see a white border around the edge.

I'd like to remove this white border if possible, but my shader is a mess at this point:

```
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable

void main(void) {

    lowp vec2 cxy = 2.0 * gl_PointCoord - 1.0;
    lowp float radius = dot(cxy, cxy);

    const lowp vec3 ambient = vec3(0.5, 0.2, 0.1);
    const lowp vec3 lightDiffuse = vec3(1, 0.5, 0.2);

    lowp vec3 normal = vec3(cxy, sqrt(1.0 - radius));
    lowp vec3 lightDir = normalize(vec3(0, -1, -0.5));
    lowp float color = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);

    lowp float delta = fwidth(radius);
    lowp float alpha = 1.0 - smoothstep(1.0 - delta, 1.0 + delta, radius);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(ambient + lightDiffuse * color, alpha);
}
```

If anyone could figure out how to remove the white border, that'd be fantastic!

Comment: @Rabbid76 After looking at the links you posted for a while, I found out the problem was I had to set alpha to false when creating the context. Could you add this as the answer? I added it myself but I can't accept it for a few days.

Comment: Just FYI: https://webglstats.com/webgl/parameter/ALIASED_POINT_SIZE_RANGE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WebGL the default is to use [pre-multiplied alpha](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/alpha-blending-pre-or-not-pre). (see [WebGL and Alpha](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-and-alpha.html))

When initializing the canvas, I has to be specified no alpha:

```
gl = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("webgl", { alpha: false });
```

see further the answers to the questions:

- [WebGL: How to correctly blend alpha channel png](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39341564/webgl-how-to-correctly-blend-alpha-channel-png/)
- [Alpha rendering difference between OpenGL and WebGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372291/alpha-rendering-difference-between-opengl-and-webgl)